# File usage as views filter?

Tags: views, files, workbench

I'm overriding the Workbench default view of files, and trying to add a filter to let the user optionally show all files that have no usage on nodes.

I see that there are ways to filter and show file usage, but I don't see a way to provide a simple toggle to the user based strictly on whether the file is in use at all.

Is this something that can be accomplished via the Views UI or will this require a custom handler?

Comment: If it's not there already, you could use `hook_views_data_alter` to alter the data item for the file_usage field and add a filter option to that array there.

Comment: I know. My question is, is it already there and I'm missing it, or do I have to tackle this programmatically? I'd like to avoid adding unnecessary code.